# D7: $node->created property not available in mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables) function?

Tags: blocks, datetime, theming

Hello I need to insert a formated date in a block template: block--delta-blocks--page-title.tpl.php

As I think this can be done using a preprocess function to set the $day, $month, $year variables:

```
function cybele_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
    $variables['day'] = format_date($node->created, 'custom', 'd' );
  }
```

But it seems $node->created is not visible here.
It works if I place it in:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
    $node = $vars['node'];
    $vars['year'] = format_date($node->created, 'custom', 'Y' );
    $vars['month'] = format_date($node->created, 'custom', 'm' );
    $vars['day'] = format_date($node->created, 'custom', 'd' );


}
```

but not in _preprocess_block function. Can someone help me do that?
Probably I need to declare in mytheme_preprocess_page but the block template won't see from there either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important difference between the two code examples you're giving, is `$node = $vars['node'];`. You can only use the variables that are available inside the function you're writing. If you declare a function `cybele_preprocess_block(&$variables)`, then the only variable you start with is $variables. In other words: inside that function, $node doesn't exist yet!

Sometimes, the current node is stored in the $variables array, so if it's in there, we can take it out again. That's what the line `$node = $vars['node'];` does: it creates a new variable $node and populates it with the value of $variables['node']. You do not have to put the node in a separate variable; you can also do this:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['day'] = format_date($variables['node']->created, 'custom', 'd' );
}
```

If the node is *not* available inside $variables (which I think is the case in _preprocess_block) you will have to load the current node. Fortunately that's rather easy in Drupal 7, because you can use menu_get_object. This will only work when viewing a node page.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  $node = menu_get_object();
  $variables['day'] = format_date($node->created, 'custom', 'd' );
}
```